# Different Gradients and color for each Data Line set

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart for creating graph in my Android Application. I wanted to know whether i can create graph like this using MPChart.

[image]

I used LineChart and added GradientDrawable in **setFillDrawable** of LineSet

```
int[] colors = {Color.parseColor("#00ff0000"), Color.parseColor("#FFB3F9E3")};
            GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TR_BL, colors);
            lineSet.setFillDrawable(gd);
```

But it is not coming as expected graph. Or suggest me best suited graph library to use for my purpose.

I have few more queries

- How can a data set name is shown along with line ?
- How the marker view can be shown only for one line , if you have multiple line set plotted

Comment: any one..out there ?.